# iOS Charts crash when chart data is appended

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, charts, ios-charts

When I try to append data to iOS Charts LineChart it crashes with message: `Fatal error: Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound` in class `BarLineScatterBubbleRenderer` at line 137.

I have created a fresh XCode project which uses Storyboards, `Charts` version 4.1.0 has been installed using cocoa pods, this is the ViewController code which I use to display the chart and append data:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let chartData = LineChartData()
    private let dataset = LineChartDataSet()
    private var dataCounter = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        chartData.append(dataset)
        chartView.data = chartData
    }

    @IBAction func onButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dataset.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(dataCounter), y: .random(in: 0...5)))
        chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
        dataCounter += 1
    }
}
```